# Transformer voltage regulation

Tags: voltage-regulator

The formula of voltage regulation is:

(voltage at no load - voltage at load or (voltage at full load)) divided by voltage at load or (voltage at full load).

$$ \frac { V_{\text{unloaded}} - {V_{\text{loaded}}}}  {V_{\text{loaded}}} $$

Why do we write voltage at load or (voltage at full load) in the denominator? I mean, why do we see the voltage regulation with respect to the load voltage instead of the no-load voltage?

Comment: I usually would see a transformer with 30% regulation as "crappy" (unless it is a neon sign transformer) and one with 5% regulation as "decent." But this is just the no-load value divided by the load value, minus 1, and then multiplied by 100 to get a percent. Which seems about like what you wrote.

Comment: I've written the equation in MathJAX for you. You should be able to modify it if you're not happy with it.

Comment: I got the definition but I am saying why do we see the Voltage regulation with respect to loaded voltage instead of no load voltage?

Comment: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronics-tutorials.ws%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2020%2F05%2Ftrans72.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronics-tutorials.ws%2Ftransformer%2Fvoltage-regulation.html&tbnid=BR72PsKZHSgtkM&vet=12ahUKEwiQ38-Eg_r1AhWWR8AKHX7FB-8QMygAegUIARDOAQ..i&docid=PMbll2Ue4e1coM&w=401&h=173&q=transformer%20regulation%20formula&ved=2ahUKEwiQ38-Eg_r1AhWWR8AKHX7FB-8QMygAegUIARDOAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**% Voltage error for Load regulation is the same as the % ratio of source resistance to total loop load.**  But this always uses the source impedance at the rated = full load relative to the external load ratio. **Thus the correct Load regulation ratio must use the Full Load in the denominator.**

\$\dfrac{V_{NL}-V_{FL}}{V_{FL}}=\dfrac{V_{NL}}{V_{FL}}-1\neq1-\dfrac{V_{NL}-V_{FL}}{V_{NL}}\$

e.g. 100x(1.1-1)/1 = 10% current ≠  (1-1.1)/1.1*100%= 9.09% or 1% error.

It seems from the other answer by Ahkil, allows both methods and define them as Up/Down Regulation instead of Load Regulation (which uses Up method relative to full load.) **In any case it is still a ratio of Impedances with or without power factor correction and the source impedance does not go up or down.**  ( So I guess this why Up Reg. Error is more common)

Answer (score 3):

I have done an online search of "transformer voltage regulation" and have found that the definition is not consistent. Most use the load voltage in the denominator but some use the no-load voltage. As a practical matter it really doesn't matter much because transformer regulation in general is very good which means the regulation (in percent) is small and thus, will only vary slightly between definitions.. For example, take the case of a 120 volt transformer where the load voltage drops to 115 volts. With the load voltage in the denominator, the load regulation comes to 4.65%. If we put the denominator as the no-load voltage, the load regulation comes to 4.17%. However, one should be careful when comparing transformers to make sure that the same definition is used.

Comment: Ah! so you are saying In practical situation the regulation is very low value so if we take no load at the denominator or we put load at the denominator. There is a very less difference so we can use both....Am I right?

Comment: And Thank you,,,Barry. : )

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer. The answer was hidden inside the definition of Voltage regulation....When we talk about down voltage regulation....the change in terminal voltage when a load current at any power factor is applied......When we talk about the up voltage regulation...it means....the ratio of the change in the terminal voltage when a load at a given power factor is removed....Credit goes to.. [ECoursesOnline](http://ecoursesonline.iasri.res.in/mod/resource/view.php?id=3283#:%7E:text=VOLTAGE%20REGULATION%20AND%20EFFICIENCY%20OF%20TRANSFORMER,-Module%203.&text=Regulation%20up%20is%20the%20ratio,removed%2C%20and%20the%20load%20voltage).

Comment: I fixed the link for you but can you edit to remove the "..." stream of consciousness punctuation? Write in proper technical English if you want to be understood. Thanks.

Comment: I am using electrical stack overflow. So I guess ask questions in a proper English not necessary. I guess.

Comment: See site policy on [Quality Standards Error](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) and "write to the best of your ability". You're asking for people to give up their time to help and read your posts. It's a matter of showing respect to your readers and keeping the site quality high.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry I agree. I was just looking it as an Electrical Engineer. But My English is not good, but I will try to write in a proper English.